# DatagridView to Textbox

Tags: datagridview, textbox

I have a list of folder paths in a data grid view.
I would like to be able to I click one of these folder paths it is automatically copied to a textbox.

Could anyone show me how this can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed I used this code below

```
if(e.RowIndex >=0)
{
DataGridViewRow row= this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

textBox1.Text = row.Cells[XMLData"].Value.ToString();
```